# Memory Leak Bug in V8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

With node.js .10.2 I ran into a memory leak that (kinda) makes sense but I believe its a bug. What do you guys think?

```
function Go(foo)
{
  var someArray = [];
  fillArrayWithLotsOfStuff(someArray);
  doSomethingWithArray(someArray,
   function(){
     setTimeout(function(){Go(foo);},0);
  });
}
```

If I move the declaration of someArray to a higher scope the memory leak is gone (for the most part). The leak is happening because the closure created by setTimeout maintains a reference to someArray when its in the function scope. The closure itself is never garbage collected either so there's still a leak though much smaller. Its as if this is recursion but its not. Yeah, Go is going to be called from within itself but it returns immediately so, IMO, the previous instance should be cleaned up.

This can be rewritten to accomplish the same thing with no leak at all. Its not a problem for me, just a topic for discussion...

---

Edit:  Modified code sample.  Forgot that setTimeout was provided an anonymous function. That makes all the difference.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I don't see how the `setTimeout` is creating a closure

Comment: By providing a function callback to setTimeout, the state of the calling function needs to be preserved so its variable are valid when the function is called, i.e. the closure.

Comment: I still don't understand. You're providing a reference, so no closure is created. It would be different if you were using `setTimeout(function () { Go(); }, 0);` - that creates a closure that holds onto `someArray`...but I would think it would be freed after the `setTimeout` completes

Comment: Me too.  I mean it probably shouldn't be creating a closure but what else would account for the added reference on the array?

Comment: How have you measured that a leak is occurring?  V8 doesn't deallocate memory very often.

Comment: Well, I think the place to look is `doSomethingWithArray` (or even `fillArrayWithLotsOfStuff`, but I feel like that one's straightforward and wouldn't hold a reference) - if that doesn't free the passed array, I would think it would leak memory there

Comment: OK, I provided the wrong sample. The leak happens when an anonymous function calls the function. See updated sample.  Still I think the leak shouldn't happen.

Comment: fillArrayWithLotsOfStuff can be just  for(var i = 0; i < 999999; someArray[i++] = i);

doSomethingWithArray can be function(fn){fn();}  for purposes of this test.

Comment: Leaving this running for a few hours will crash the node process. Memory is never cleaned up, even if after n loops there a "sleep" period of no activity.